# How this Linear Equations Got that solution with this form?

Tags: linear-algebra

Recently, I got an equation with this form:
$$ (x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 = (x-x_2)^2 +(y-y_2)^2 = (x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2$$

Yes, It's from a question about calculating center point from three given points on a circle.

Reduce it, and I got this:
$$ \begin{cases}
      2(x_2 - x_1)x + 2(y_2-y_1)y = -x_1^2-y_1^2+x_2^2+y_2^2 \\
      2(x_3 - x_1)x + 2(y_3-y_1)y = -x_1^2-y_1^2 +x_2^2+y_2^2 
   \end{cases} \tag{1} \label{1}$$

Well, it an linear equation, Using Cramer ruler I can get the solution,
but The Solution given by my book Taking this Form:
$$ x= \frac{ \begin{vmatrix} 1 & x_1^2+y_1^2 & y_1 \\
                                  1 & x_2^2+y_2^2 & y_2 \\ 
                                  1 & x_3^2+y_3^2 & y_3 \\ \end{vmatrix}}
            {2\begin{vmatrix} 1 & x_1 & y_1 \\
                                  1 & x_2 & y_2 \\ 
                                  1 & x_3 & y_3 \\ \end{vmatrix}}$$
$$ y= \frac{ \begin{vmatrix} 1 & x_1 & x_1^2+y_1^2 \\
                             1 & x_2 & x_2^2+y_2^2 \\ 
                             1 & x_3 & x_3^2+y_3^2 \\ \end{vmatrix}}
            {2\begin{vmatrix} 1 & x_1 & y_1 \\
                                  1 & x_2 & y_2 \\ 
                                  1 & x_3 & y_3 \\ \end{vmatrix}}$$

How this come from? I assume this form are coming from some rewritten of equation $\ref{1}$ . Can someone tell me how to rewrite equation $\ref{1}$ so I can use Cramer ruler and get the solution with the form above?

Comment: There are typos in the rhs of the second line of $(1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & a & u \\
  1 & b & v \\
  1 & c & w
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & a & u \\
  0 & b-a & v-u \\
  0 & c-a & w-u
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
  b-a & v-u \\
  c-a & w-u
\end{vmatrix}$$

> The $3\times 3$ determinant looks more elegant than the $2\times 2$ one.